# How create a batch file that opens a 32bit cmd prompt as Admin to run another batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that I currently have to do the following to run:

1. Open SYSWOW64\cmd.exe as admininstrator (it's a 32bit application)
2. cd c:\mybatchfilelocation\
3. then run my batch file batchfile.bat

I'd like to just be able to run one batch as admin that automatically opens the SYSWOW64\cmd.exe as administrator (prompting for admin username and password is ok) and then have that run my batchfile.bat

I've seen where you can do it if you pre-specify the /user:machinename\administor in the batch file before running it and it only prompts for password but this needs to be deployed to customers and I can't rely on them editing the file.  I need it to run with prompts when input is required by them.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Bill, I no longer need to worry about the SYSWOW64 part.  I only need to be able to figure out how to have a batch file open a cmd prompt as an administrator and have that cmd run another batch file in that same directory.

Comment: My questions are:  
1. Why is it needed to run 32-bit version of cmd.exe?  
2. Why does your script need to run as administrator?

Comment: Because the software is old VB COM so you have register them using 32 bit version.  Didn't used too on server 2003 until UAC with Windows 2008 server which is default now.

Comment: So you have to register what? Please tell specifically what you need to accomplish, not how you think it needs to be done. That is, seek an answer to the problem, not just an answer to a question.

Comment: Sorry - each sentence was the answer to each answer, just to be clear.

Comment: It's a slew of things - most of which are in-house legacy VB dlls and some third-party dlls you wouldn't have heard of.  The standard microsoft Capicom.dll is probably the only one you'd be familiar with.

Comment: OK...so what does all of this have to do with opening the 32-bit version of cmd.exe?

Comment: By the way, I did some research and you are 100% correct.  Our batch file runs just fine through the 64bit version and we do NOT have to use the 32bit SYSWOW version.  Someone made it a few years ago when 2008 and its UAC defaults and for some reason thought it needed the 32 bit version.  It's just "been that way" in the install guide ever since.  Thanks for the insight!  Not sure what I should do with this question now.

Comment: If the batch file (shell script) needs to run as administrator, simply right-click it and choose "Run as administrator."

Comment: I did some more research, yes your suggestion would work fine but we don't know what drive our customers will try to install our software on so when the batch file tries run the regsvr32 from the c:\windows\System directory, there's no reference to where our DLLs are sitting - could C: drive could be D: drive, etc.  So, currently, we have them open a cmd, change the directory to where our install was extracted to and then have them run the batch file from that directory int he cmd prompt.  (I greatly appreciate all the help so far, BTW)

Comment: IMO the whole approach is completely wrong-headed. Customers should not be registering the DLLs; you need to provide them an installer that does that for them.

Comment: Well, that's a given but, unfortunately, doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Have you tried using runas?
Or psexec.exe from sysinternals?  Using that locally should work no problem.

Comment: Do you have the installation path for your application stored somewhere (such as a registry setting)? If so, you can reference this stored path from a shell script (batch file) and in this way your customers do not need to know it. IMO you should seek the solution to the problem rather than an answer to a specific question.

Comment: +1 @Bill, no we don't but I believe that's the solution that we'll need to use since we'll have to know the path to our batch in order to automatically run it file as administrator via the CMD prompt.  They client could extract it to any drive on their server so we can't assume it's on C: or D:, etc.

Comment: Even better is to use an installer that can register the DLLs automatically at install time. I know [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) can do this and it's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register 32-bit DLLs in a cmd shell script (batch file) on a machine that might be running 64-bit Windows...

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set REGSVR=
if defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (
  set REGSVR=%SystemRoot%\system32\regsvr32.exe
) else (
  set REGSVR=%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe
)
%REGSVR% /s "C:\Path\my dll file.dll"
...
endlocal
```

**UPDATE**

The **if defined** line should not use **not**. It should be as above.

Comment: This code: http://pastebin.com/sq6YTweA produced these results: http://pastebin.com/qMJAMNWr on both a 32bit 2008 server and a 64bit 2008 R2 server.  I'm sure I'm missing something.  I'm helping out in an area that is not my forte so sorry for the noobness here.

Comment: The WOW 32-bit emulator uses the PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 environment variable to tell the "true" processor architecture if you're running a 32-bit application on 64-bit Windows. If you run the code from 64-bit cmd.exe, you will see SysWOW64 instead of System32. If you are running from 32-bit mode, you will see system32, which the system automatically redirects to SysWOW64. Run it from the 64-bit version and observe the results.

Comment: Also, the code should say **if defined** rather than **if not defined** (see corrected answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can you include additional software? There are [several](http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/) [commandline](http://wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/03/27/elevate-a-process-at-the-command-line-in-vista.aspx) [utilities](http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/) available for this purpose. Or you could use a VBScript to launch the batch script:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
app.ShellExecute "C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\cmd.exe", "/c batchfile.bat" _
  , "C:\mybatchfilelocation\", "runas", 1
```